# ComponentDidMount only renders data on the page when i click on it the second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch posts data from fb and render them with componentDidMount, but its not rendering anything til i click on in the second time !

```
async componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({ isloading: true})
  listData=await
    this.fetchPosts(listData);
    console.log(listData)
    this.setState({ isloading: false}) 
}
```

```
    fetchPosts=(listData)=>{
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
      window.FB.api(
        '/me',
        'GET',
        {"fields":"","access_token":""},

        function(response) {...});
         }        
       });       
       if(!listData)reject(new Error('Error: No listData passed in'))
       resolve(listData)     
    })        
   }
```

here's how I'm rendering:

```
if (isloading===true) {
      return (
        <Spin size="large" />
      )
    }
      return (...)
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the first call to `setState` (`this.setState({ isloading: true})`) will change the state before the last one (`this.setState({ isloading: false})`). To enforce that, use something like `this.setState({isloading: true}, () => {....})`.

Comment: it didn't solve the issue

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? Is the `Spin` component displayed until you click ? Beside the state synchronization problem you also don't seem to add the data from the API (`listData`) to the state.